# Tailwind screen function break the sass compiler

Tags: sass, tailwind-css

I've got the screen function used in my global.scss

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.h-main {
  font-size: 74px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;

  @media screen(sm) { 
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}
```

and here my tailwind config

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
        'gradient-conic':
          'conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
      },
    },
    screens: {
      'sm': '600px',
      'md': '900px',
      'lg': '1200px',
      'xl': '1536px',
      'xs': '0px',
    }
  },
  plugins: [],
  
}
```

the sass compiler gives me this error:

```
SassError: expected "{".
   ╷
69 │   @media screen(sm) {
   │                ^
   ╵
```

Like it's not recognizing the tailwind function. What am I missing?

[docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#screen)

What I expect is that screen function produce a media query build on the breakpoints specified inside the tailwind config, like stated in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

It seems SCSS syntax does not permit the `screen()` function. As a work-around, you could consider using [`theme()`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#theme) in a regular media query:

```scss
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.h-main {
  font-size: 74px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;

  @media (min-width: theme('screens.sm')) {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}
```

See this compile successfully in [this Sass Playground](https://sass-lang.com/playground/#eJxVzUEOgjAQQNF9TzE7YFEC0WhSNlylwmgnaaeEDqnRcHdRY9Tlf5vftr1Y8pl4hJNN2KlvDzFMkZEl/eoi5EkIN1S108ESw10BnCOLTnRDA8f9dO0+lJEuTgwcmuZpQ/RxNpAdyTbboA84koUyEOtMozgD4jBgWaRhRuRUp1BU1evxd9k178uq1ge2Xj+W).

Comment: ty for the hint, it's helping. Anyway, it still gives error even inside a css, because the syntax conflicts with the standard @media syntax...

Comment: "it still gives error Inside a css" – "it" meaning what? What is the error? Also, you'd want to have this in a `.scss` file, not a `.css` file.

Comment: it gives the very same error about screen syntax. To me is pretty musch the same, I can use both css or scss

Comment: "it" meaning what specifically? It should compile successfully as per [this Sass Playground](https://sass-lang.com/playground/#eJxVzUEOgjAQQNF9TzE7YFEC0WhSNlylwmgnaaeEDqnRcHdRY9Tlf5vftr1Y8pl4hJNN2KlvDzFMkZEl/eoi5EkIN1S108ESw10BnCOLTnRDA8f9dO0+lJEuTgwcmuZpQ/RxNpAdyTbboA84koUyEOtMozgD4jBgWaRhRuRUp1BU1evxd9k178uq1ge2Xj+W)

Comment: it stands for the sass compiler, really don't know why